# Правильно ли расставлены знаки в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Наречия "искренно" и "нежно" подчёркивают хрупкость и чистоту любовного чувства

Comment: Наречия *характеризуют*, *выражают*, *указывают на*, *позволяют понять*.

Comment: Может быть, вам будет лучше написать небольшой отрывок, чтобы понять, как лучше изменить текст. Например, "Применяя к словам наречия "искренно" и "нежно" можно подчеркнуть хрупкость и чистоту любовного чувства". Или "...позволяют раскрыть всю чистоту..."